# unused arguments (impulse = "e", response = c("prod", "rw", "U"), boot = FALSE)

Tags: r

I am trying to follow the common example that calculates impulse response functions of a VAR model using data from Canada and I keep getting the error from the title:

```
library(vars)

data(Canada)
## For VAR
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
irf(var.2c, impulse = "e", response = c("prod", "rw", "U"), boot =
      FALSE)
```

With the following error:

> Error in irf(var.2c, impulse = "e", response = c("prod", "rw", "U"), boot = FALSE) : 
>     unused arguments (impulse = "e", response = c("prod", "rw", "U"), boot = FALSE)

Note that the code is an exact copy of the example used in the description of the package `vars` in R.

I am using R version 3.2.5, Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) and is running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: Code works fine on Windows, R 3.3.0, vars_1.5-2. Please update your post with output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you think is an external problem?

Comment: Maybe update R and the package.

Comment: Works for me too, why dont you try irf(var.2c) so that you dont pass any param and check for the error then.

Comment: It works when I updated R. Thanks for the advice! Can you guys put is as the answer so I label the question as answered. Cheers!